# Can I send sensor (couple of bytes) over beacon?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, beacon

I want to send some sensor data over BLE to multiple nodes.
I thought of changing advertising data at 4Hz. Can it be done?

Answer (score 5):

Yes!  It is a common approach to use a BLE beacon packet to advertise sensor data.  A few points:

1. Embedded BLE platforms typically allow advertising at a minimum of 10Hz, and let you change the advertisement between transmissions.  I have done this on the Nordic 52x chips, but hopefully STM32 supports it as well.
2. BLE 4.0 advertising packets are limited to 23 usable data bytes, but you typically need to reserve a few to indicate it is "your" transmission.  There are significant further restrictions if you intend to use iOS devices to scan the transmissions.  If using Android, Linux, or other embedded system scanners you can use nearly the full 23 bytes.
3. Keep in mind that anybody in radio range can scan for these advertisements and read the data.  Make sure the sensor data are not sensitive enough to warrant a security layer.